# deleting all documents with out dropping index in elasticsearch java API

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Is there any simple Java API to delete all the documents from elastic search with out dropping the index.

I know that we could get all the ids and delete each document one by one

```
DeleteResponse response = _client.prepareDelete(INDEX, TYPE, id)
            .setRefresh(true)
            .execute()
            .actionGet();
```

But I was looking for TRUNCATE kind of scenario.

At present I am deleting the index and recreating the mapping in unit tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [delete-by-query plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.2/plugins-delete-by-query.html) in order to achieve that.

You need to install it on all nodes with

```
sudo bin/plugin install delete-by-query
```

Then you can add this dependency to your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>delete-by-query</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And finally you'll be able to use the [`DeleteByQueryRequestBuilder`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/2.2/plugins/delete-by-query/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/action/deletebyquery/DeleteByQueryRequestBuilder.java) in order to delete all your documents after your tests.

Comment: Thanks Val.  I am using a in memory elastic search Iet me see how can achieve this.

Comment: This should help, then: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elasticsearch/XpaJo_rIglo, i.e. simply add the JAR to your classpath.

Answer (score 1):

If it were me, I wouldn't try to truncate data in ES like this. Instead, I would use -0 and -1 suffixed indices and an index alias pointed at the index I considered "hot."

So for example if you have an index called `my-data`, I would replace that index with `my-data-0` and `my-data-1`. Then, I would define an alias for `my-data` pointed at `my-data-0`

If I wanted to truncate my index, I'd simply swap the alias for `my-data` to point it at `my-data-1`, which would be empty, and away from `my-data-0`, which obviously isn't since you're trying to truncate it. After that, I would delete `my-data-0` and then immediately recreate the index. Next time I need an empty index, I'd do the same thing all over again, just in reverse.

You should note that this sort of operation can be handled atomically (eg https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index-aliases.html).

You should also note that it is gonna be much much faster this way, especially on large indices... and it'll make schema evolution a lot easier to manage as well. Please consider if that would accomplish what you need. If so, I think you'll find that much nicer to work with than the delete by query.

Comment: I agree with you but what I was looking for is for unit tests clearing data from in memory elastic search.

Comment: Overlooked that part. My apologies. For in memory unit testing, Val is right. Delete by and move on.

Answer (score 1):

Use a DeleteByQueryRequest

```
DeleteByQueryRequest delete = new DeleteByQueryRequest("inser index name here");
delete.setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery());
this.client.deleteByQuery(delete, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);//RestHighLevelClient
```

Answer (score 0):

You could find elaseticsearchservice.functioncall - it is because i have written all es operation in a separate class

### Async way --

```
          DeleteByQueryRequestBuilder deleteByQueryRequestBuilder = elasticsearchService.deleteAllDocument(PRODUCTSINDEX);
            deleteByQueryRequestBuilder.execute(new ActionListener<BulkIndexByScrollResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(BulkIndexByScrollResponse bulkIndexByScrollResponse) {
                    if (bulkIndexByScrollResponse.getDeleted() == 0) {

                    } else if (bulkIndexByScrollResponse.getDeleted() > 0) {
                       // getDeleted() gives you how many docs in that index have been deleted
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Exception e) {
                   //reason like no index exists, improper connection etc
                }
            });

  ------------------------------------------------------------------  
      public DeleteByQueryRequestBuilder deleteAllDocument(String indexName) {
            DeleteByQueryRequestBuilder DeleteByQueryRequestBuilder = DeleteByQueryAction.INSTANCE.newRequestBuilder(client)
                    .filter(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery())
                    .source(indexName);
            return DeleteByQueryRequestBuilder;

        }
```

---

### Normal way--

```
public void deleteAllProduct(RoutingContext routingContext) {
        long starttime = System.currentTimeMillis();
       elasticsearchService.deleteAllDocument1(PRODUCTSINDEX);

    }
--------------------------------------------------------------

  public void deleteAllDocument1(String indexName) {
        ListenableActionFuture<BulkIndexByScrollResponse> execute = DeleteByQueryAction.INSTANCE.newRequestBuilder(client)
                .filter(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery())
                .source(indexName).execute();


        try {
            BulkIndexByScrollResponse   bulkIndexByScrollResponse = execute.get();
            if (bulkIndexByScrollResponse.getDeleted()>0)
            {
                System.out.println(bulkIndexByScrollResponse.getDeleted());
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can truncate by looping through search results and deleting them:

```
    public static void truncateESNamespace(String namespace) {
    client.admin().indices().prepareRefresh(namespace).get();
    SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch(namespace).setSize(10000).get();
    while (response.getHits().totalHits > 0) {
        BulkRequestBuilder bulkRequest = client.prepareBulk();
        Arrays.stream(response.getHits().getHits()).forEach(h -> bulkRequest.add(client.prepareDelete(h.getIndex(), h.getType(), h.getId())));
        bulkRequest.get();
        client.admin().indices().prepareRefresh(namespace).get();
        response = client.prepareSearch(namespace).setSize(10000).get();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the `RestHighLevelClient` you can do the following:

```
DeleteByQueryRequest request = new DeleteByQueryRequest(index);
request.setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery());

client.deleteByQuery(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```